# Kohana 3: How to find the active item in a dynamic menu

Tags: php, menu, kohana-3

Maybe not the best explanation, but hear me out. Say I have the following in a config file called *menu.php*:

```
// Default controller is 'home' and default action is 'index'
return array(
   'items' => array(
      'Home' => '',
      'News' => 'news',
      'Resources' => 'resources',
   ),
);
```

I now want to print this out as a menu, which is pretty simple:

```
foreach(Kohana::config('menu.items') as $title => $uri)
{
    echo '<li>' . HTML::anchor($uri, $title) . '</li>';
}
```

However, I want to find the `$uri` that matches the current controller and action. And if the action is the default one or not. What I want to end up with is that menu item should have `id="active-item"` if it is the linking to the current controller, but the default action. And `id="active-subitem` if it is linking to the current controller and the action is not the default one. Hope that made sense...

Anyone able to help me out here? Both in how to do this in Kohana 3 and also how it *should* be done in Kohana 3. I'm sure there are lots of ways, but yeah... any help is welcome :)

---

Examples:

- domain.com -- *Home* should be *active-item* since it is the default controller
- domain.com/home -- *Home* should be *active-item*
- domain.com/home/index -- *Home* should be *active-item* since *index* is the default action
- domain.com/resources -- *Resources* should be *active-item*
- domain.com/resources/get/7 -- *Resources* should be *active-subitem* since *get* is not the default action

Answer (score 1):

You could do it a few ways

### CSS

I often use this method. I attach a class to the body element of every page to identify.

**HTML**

```
<style type="text/css">
body.home #home-link {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
</style>

<body class="home">
<ul>
    <li id="home-link">Home</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Advantages are it's simple to implement. Disadvantages are you need to list a lot of selectors, one for each section (not such a problem on a small brochure site).

### Add via Controller

You can also add via controller

**Controller**

```
public function action_about() {

    $this->template->active = 'about';

}
```

**View**

```
foreach(Kohana::config('menu.items') as $title => $uri)
{
    echo '<li' . (($active === $uri) ? ' class="active"' : NULL) . '>' . HTML::anchor($uri, $title) . '</li>';
}
```

Then of course, you just style the list element with the class of `active`. Advantages are that you only define the CSS once.